# Sharepoint. Access denied on document librarry item

Tags: sharepoint, access-denied, sharepointdocumentlibrary, registering, tagprefix

I faced to problem with sharepoint permissions. When I try to open document library item (.aspx) - Access denied.

I created specific group with read perrmissions, included user on it and applyed it on doc lib, and doc lib item (.aspx). Doc lib is alowed to view item, but then try to open it - throws access denied.

.aspx in doc lib has a webpart. When I try to load blank .aspx - everything ok with permissions -allows, but when I'm trying to register webpart Tagprefix: 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="ICTWebparts" Namespace="ICT.WebParts" Assembly="ICT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cece68aca32fb0ba" %> - Access denied.

Whats the problem? Why it throws an access denied when i'm trying to register .dll in aspx?

I would be grateful for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this kind of problem before, and when you're in a webpart with an external .aspx you need to force your credential with the default one which is the credential you're logged in, just like this (in code behind):

```
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```